# Index pattern is not visualize in kibana

Tags: api, rest, elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-file

I am using Elastic Search 8.1.2 with Kibana
[image: index pattern is not showing in Kibana 8.1.2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your space or your role doesn't allow you to access the index pattern management feature (see screenshot below)

At the space level, you can give access to index pattern management:

[image: Space config]

Or you can also do it at the role level:

[image: Role config]